# How to read an image from Google Drive using Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read image from drive and convert to binary.How can I do that? I used this code but not get the actual image.

```
link = urllib.request.urlopen("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CT12YIeF0xcc8cwhBpvR-Oq0AFOABwsw/view?usp=sharing").read()
image_base64 = base64.encodestring(link)
```

Answer (score -1):

**1. Download the image to your computer.**

**2. You can use cv2 to convert an image to binary like so:**

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('imgs/mypic.jpg',2)
ret, bw_img = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```